# Rails action kicks me out, but only on ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, security

I have the following action, `appointments_for_week`:

```
class StylistsController < ApplicationController

  def appointments_for_week
    stylist = Stylist.find(params[:id])
    date = Time.zone.parse(params[:date])
    appointments = stylist.salon.appointments_flat(stylist.id,
                                                   (date + 1.day).beginning_of_week.advance(:days => -1),
                                                   (date + 1.day).end_of_week.advance(:days => -1) + 1.day)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @appointments }
    end 
  end
```

Something really weird is happening. If I log in and then simply browse to this action's route, nothing happens. I get a blank page, which is what I would expect. If I then go to another page and refresh, I'm still logged in, which is of course what I would expect.

However, if I do a request on this action via ajax, it kicks me out. I find this incredibly strange. If I add a `before_filter` to skip authentication, I no longer get kicked out, but I of course don't want to skip authentication. I don't understand why this action can be accessed via a regular request but not an ajax request.

What could be happening here?

(I'm on Rails 3.2.1, in case it matters.)

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "kicks me out"?

Comment: I mean I'm no longer authenticated and, when I refresh the page, I'm redirected to the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out, two seconds after I spent forever putting together my question.

The ajax request was `POST`. Switching to `GET` made it work.

Interestingly, it was `POST` before and the same exact JavaScript worked. The only thing I changed was that I updated my version of jQuery, so I guess it must have had something to do with it.

Comment: That makes it sounds like the csrf protection was being triggered